# Is it okay to have more than one foreign key from one table to the same table?

Tags: mysql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

Say I have a table as shown below:-

```
Employee

employee Id -- Primary Key
manager Id -- Foreign Key Relationship with employee id as manager is also an employee
subordinates -- List<Employee Ids> another foreign key relationship to the same table.
```

I am using Spring so a minimalistic class wud be something like the one showed below:-

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "employee")
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "employee_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String employeeId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Employee> subordinates;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Employee manager;

}
}
```

The above does not give me any issues when I compile and run.

So my question basically is is it okay to have one table having multiple foreign key relationship with itself or another table or will I fall into some trouble later on if I follow this schema.

Thanks,

Comment: I cannot answer the spring boot side of the question, but from a database angle, you cannot add a foreign key that points to many rows. Besides, that would introduce an unnecessary redundancy, because the foreign key to the manager already contains the complete information. The list of subordinates should not be modeled in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you dont want a 1 to 1 relationship. You merge 2 tables having a 1 to 1 relationship and make them one table.

In your example the managerId and the employee relashionship is 1 to 1.
Merge them: rename the table to employee/manager and replace the managerId column with a Boolean column "isManager" that takes the value 1 if that employee is a manager and 0 if not.

The other subordinates column is fine.
You can have a 1 to multiple relashionship within the table itself.

But in you should think about the implementation and where to place the foreign key in a 1 to many relationship. 
Ex: a department can have multiple enployees, but an employee can only be in 1 department. That's a 1 to many relashionship. But when implementing, the foreign key should be in the employees table referencing the department table.

Also a general answer to your question:

Yes. You can have multiple foreign keys to the same table if unavoidable. 
Also avoid having a 1 to 1 relationship between 2 tables.